# NavigateUrl Remove "amp;" from URL

Tags: c#, html, url-routing

Can someone please advise me how I can remove "amp;" from the `Url` generated from a `HyperLink`?

The hyperlink code below is using `GetRouteUrl` to transform the `Url` so that it contains the category name rather than just the `CategoryId`.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl='<%#: 
            Page.GetRouteUrl("ProductRoute", 
            new {
                 DepartmentId = Eval("departId"), 
                 CategoryId = Eval("categoryId"), 
                 CatName = Eval("CatName")})
            %>' 
            text='<%# Eval("CatName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

The code above produces this Url:

```
"/LL_live_2012/Products/Madonna?DepartmentId=23&amp;CategoryId=13"
```

The Product page then uses `Request.QueryString` to obtain the `CategoryId`, but this is set to `NULL` due to the "amp;"

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/entity-escape-characters.php

Comment: If you remove the `&`, you will be left with `/LL_live_2012/Products/Madonna?DepartmentId=23CategoryId=13`. I doubt the website will be able to handle a DepartmentId of "23CategoryId=13".

Comment: Sounds like it's being encoded somewhere on route. You could try decoding it.

Try HttpUtility Methods
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adwtk1fy.aspx

Comment: Keith - I want to include a `&` inbetween the DepartmentId=23 and CategoryId=13, but I don't want the 'amp;'.

Comment: @user3385177, it seems like an encoding issue, but I cannot reproduce it. When I set the `NavigateUrl` from a codebehind it was set properly. You may want to try that.

Comment: Nathan - can you supply the navigateurl code that you used?